# Printing Calculation result

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a print function that would help me with printing the results of the addition, subtraction, etc.
I've tried to do this in a switch - case statement, but it doesn't seems to be working.
Is there any easier ways to implement this print() function?
Secondly, in case of exception, how can I manage exceptions if for instance one of the operations throw an exception. such as 3/0!

for this program I have a Calculator class and a Program, where all this will be tested.

```
public class Calculator
{
    public double Add(double x, double y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public double Subtract(double x, double y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }

    public double Multiply(double x, double y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }

    public double Power(double x, double y)
    {
        return Math.Pow(x, y);
    }

    public void PrintCalculation(string action)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
             case "Add":
            Console.WriteLine("Sum is: {0}", Add(x, y));
            break;
        case "Subtract":
            Console.WriteLine("Division is: {0}", Subtract(x, y));
            break;
        case "Multiply":
            Console.WriteLine("Multiply is: {0}", Multiply(x, y);
            break;
        case "Power":
            Console.WriteLine("Power is: {0}", Power(x, y);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the `Main` function

```
namespace MyCalculator
{
    public class Program : Calculator
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Calculator myCal = new Calculator();

            myCal.Add(2, 3);
            myCal.Subtract(3, 3);
            myCal.Multiply(5, 5);
            myCal.Power(2, 3);

             myCal.PrintCalculation("Add");
        myCal.PrintCalculation("Subtract");
        myCal.PrintCalculation("Multiply");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have fixed a typo `case "Subtract` -> `case "Subtract"`. I guess that was not relevant for the question. was it?

Comment: `myCal.Add(2, 3);` What happens to the value returned by this function?

Comment: You need to add `break` statements in each case: `case "Add":  Console.WriteLine("Sum is: {0}", Add(x, y)); break;`

Comment: Instead of `myCal.PrintCalculation(Add)` you have to pass strings: `myCal.PrintCalculation("Add")`

Comment: You also have to add `x` and `y` to the method arguments; currently they're undedfined in that method: `public void PrintCalculation(string action, double x, double y)`

Comment: You also need to set `x` and `y` and add some closing `)`

Comment: Thanks. It reduced many of the errors. Though, in the main it complains about the print function's arguments. It takes 3 arguments, but I passe 1 argument (Add , Subtract etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with the code that are causing compiler errors, such as missing parenthesis, quotes, and break statements. But I think the main issue is that you're not taking in the values of `x` and `y` to your `PrintCalculation` method, so they are undefined in the body of that method.

To fix this, you can just add them to the argument list as you have with the other methods:

```
public static void PrintCalculation(string action, double x , double y)
```

But notice that you're doing a string comparison here, which can be prone to errors due to case sensitivity (what happens if they write `"add"` instead of `"Add"`?). A different option might be to create an `enum` to represent valid actions. This also serves to restrict the input allowed to only values we can do something with (previously the user may have tried to enter `"Divide"`, and been confused when nothing happened):

```
public enum Action { Add, Subtract, Multiply, Power }
```

Then your method could be changed to accommodate the enum instead of a string. We can also make the class and methods `static`, since there is no state required:

```
public static class Calculator
{
    public enum Action { Add, Subtract, Multiply, Power }

    public static double Add(double x, double y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }

    public static double Subtract(double x, double y)
    {
        return x - y;
    }

    public static double Multiply(double x, double y)
    {
        return x * y;
    }

    public static double Power(double x, double y)
    {
        return Math.Pow(x, y);
    }

    public static void PrintCalculation(Action action, double x , double y)
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case Action.Add:
                Console.WriteLine("The sum of {0} and {1} is: {2}", 
                    x, y, Add(x, y));
                break;

            case Action.Subtract:
                Console.WriteLine("The difference between {0} and {1} is: {2}", 
                    x, y, Subtract(x, y));
                break;

            case Action.Multiply:
                Console.WriteLine("The product of {0} and {1} is: {2}", 
                    x, y, Multiply(x, y));
                break;

            case Action.Power:
                Console.WriteLine("{0} raised to the power of {1} is: {2}", 
                    x, y, Power(x, y));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

With these changes, we can now use the class like:

```
private static void Main(string[] cmdArgs)
{
    var first = 7;
    var second = 3;

    Calculator.PrintCalculation(Calculator.Action.Add, first, second);
    Calculator.PrintCalculation(Calculator.Action.Subtract, first, second);
    Calculator.PrintCalculation(Calculator.Action.Multiply, first, second);
    Calculator.PrintCalculation(Calculator.Action.Power, first, second);

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Ahh I like this, it's logical to have the output text vary depending on the calculation action.

Comment: This is a very nice and easily understandable implementation. I like the idea of using the enumerations.

Answer (score 3):

A few issues, first of all you are not passing strings into PrintCalculation(string s).  The format should be something like:

`PrintCalculation("Add");`

As the function is currently defined.  Also in PrintCalculation() you call your calculation functions which are then passed undefined values of x and y.  They are not members of the class or the class method itself.

For example you are trying to call `Add(x,y)` inside of `PrintCalculation("Add")`, but you never give it an x or y in that function.  Instead the function should be defined

```
public void PrintCalculation(string action, double x, double y){
// code here
}
```

And it should be called with

```
PrintCalculation("Add", 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take advantage of logging the actions without requiring a switch case at all.  The example below allows you to set an `Action<string>` for logging the results dynamically.

```
public class Calculator
{
    public Action<string> LogAction { get; set;}

    private double PerformCalculation(string calculationName, string format, double x, double y, Func<double, double, double> calcFunction)
    {
        double value = calcFunction(x, y);
        LogAction?.Invoke(string.Format(format, x, y, value));

        return calcFunction(x, y);
    }

    public double Add(double x, double y)
    {
        string format = "The sum of {0} and {1} is: {2}";
        return PerformCalculation("Add", format, x, y, (a, b) => a + b);
    } 

    public double Subtract(double x, double y)
    {
        string format = "The difference between {0} and {1} is: {2}";
        return PerformCalculation("Subtract", format, x, y, (a, b) => a - b);
    }

    public double Multiply(double x, double y)
    {
        string format = "The product of {0} and {1} is: {2}";
        return PerformCalculation("Multiply", format, x, y, (a, b) => a * b);
    }

    public double Power(double x, double y)
    {
        string format = "{0} raised to the power of {1} is: {2}";
        return PerformCalculation("Power", format, x, y, (a, b) => Math.Pow(a, b));
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Calculator myCal = new Calculator();
    myCal.LogAction = Console.WriteLine; // Sets all calculation output to the console.

    myCal.Add(2, 3);
    myCal.Subtract(3, 3);
    myCal.Multiply(5, 5);
    myCal.Power(2, 3);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you all very much for all the great tips. It really helps me as a new comer to c#.

Comment: This is very clever!

Comment: I have applied the changes that everyone has suggest above. Trying these different methods of implementations gave me a deeper understanding knowledge about my errors. :)

Comment: @RufusL thanks!  After seeing yours I'd want to revise this to where `PerformCalculation` can accept a string to use when outputting.

Answer (score 0):

Your problemn is: you start the method to do something
Main:

```
myCal.Add(2, 3);
```

Class:

```
public double Add(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

but you don't store the outcome anywhere. You see, the method knows to return something, but on the other end is nothing to receive it like

```
double i = myCal.Add(2, 3);
```

or, as an alternative you can store your numbers in the class

```
public double _outcome;

public void Add(double x, double y)
{
    _outcome = x + y;
}
```

and in main

```
myCal.PrintCalculation(myCal._outcome.ToString());
```

As an alternative (to do it the way you actually want it to)

Main:

```
myCal.TmpNumberOne = 1;
myCal.TmpNumberTwo = 2;

myCal.PrintCalculation("Add");
```

Class:

```
public double TmpNumberOne;
public double TmpNumberTwo;

public double Add(double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}     

public void PrintCalculation(string action)
{
    switch (action)
    {
        case "Add":
            Console.WriteLine("Sum is: {0}", Add(TmpNumberOne, TmpNumberTwo).ToString());
            break;
    }
}
```

To your final question: you want exceptionhandling, first you coudl achieve this by adding an if-statement to your method to check for invalid inputs, or you take the holy

```
try
{
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

you can paste your code inside try, when an error would occur that stops the program entirely, the code in catch code is executed instead. If you are fancy you can print out the exception with

```
ex.ToString();
```

don't forget to convert your double values to string, otherwise this will throw an error